# sails.js relifting with mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, mocha.js

I have certain mocha tests that need to re-lift sails with a different configuration that mocks certain policies using the moduleLoaderOverride.  In general, this is working, but it seems sails is not lowering and re-lifting properly.

The utility file that does all the management of the sails instance for tests:

```
// util 
var Sails = require('sails/lib/app'),
    sails;

module.exports = {
  sailsInstance: undefined,
  testConfigs: {}, 

  start: function(callback) {
    this.sailsInstance = new Sails();
    /*
      This config will NOT be enforced for the remaining tests,
      it is just a quick lift so our code can use sails config
      parser and extract the other configs easily.
     */
    this.sailsInstance.lift({}, function(err, server) {
      sails = server;
      // populate this.testConfigs object here
      this.configureSails('defaultConfig', callback);
    }.bind(this));
  },

  end: function(callback) {
    this.sailsInstance.lower(callback);
  },


  configureSails: function(configName, callback) {
    console.log('LIFTING WITH:', configName);

    var launchConfig = this.testConfigs[configName];

    console.log('LOWERING');
    this.sailsInstance.lower(function (err) {
      console.log('LOWERED');

      this.sailsInstance = new Sails();

      console.log('LIFTING');
      this.sailsInstance.lift( launchConfig, function(err, server) {
        console.log('LIFTED');
        global.sails = server;

        return callback(err);
      }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this));
  },
```

In the test-bootstrap file:

```
// test-bootstrap
before(function (done){  
   util.start(done);
});

after(function(done) {
  testUtils.end(done);
});
```

In the user test file:

```
// user test
describe('User permissions', function() {
  before(function(done){
    util.configureSails('enablePolicies', done);
  });
});
```

So, everything goes well in the bootstrap, but fails when it's lifted a second time in the user test file.  The exact log I'm getting is this:

```
LIFTING WITH: defaultConfig
LOWERING
LOWERED
LIFTING
LIFTED

  User permissions
LIFTING WITH: enablePolicies
LOWERING
    1) "before all" hook

  0 passing (3s)
  1 failing

  1) User permissions "before all" hook:
     Uncaught Error: Trying to start server on port 1337 but can't...Something else is probably running on that port!
Please disable the other server, or choose a different port and try again.




LOWERED
LIFTING
// npm error spam
```

I've seen this error when sails tries to lift twice in a row, but that shouldn't be happening since I'm lowering it first.  I also suspect a scope issue since the start function does two lifts without running over the port, but user test fails.  The only difference I see there is configureSails function is being called from the user test file instead of the util file, but I'm not sure if that's the problem or how to solve it if it is the problem.

Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not try different port at user test?

Comment: very interesting result... with `port: 1338` in config, I get the same error for can't lift on port 1337.  Did some more digging and found if I don't return the callback, the error doesn't show up - it will lift successfully.  But obviously this hangs the entire test suite and nothing else is done.

Comment: Ok, I've remove all lifts and confirmed that sails.lower is causing the error.  This seems more like a bug at this point.

Comment: that's make sense, since generally we never wait until sails actually lowered. maybe you can use different approach, without waiting until sails actually lowered.

Comment: I meet same problem with you when I am trying to run `npm test`. And I dig into the source code of sails in `lib/hook/https/start.js`. I really don't know why in the async flow the server listen succeed with no error and has `address()` result, but in `verify` the result just gone!

Comment: At last I restart my computer then it works! I really don't know which process is using that port!